# customized AlertDialog generates errors

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I want to create a customised `alertDialog` using the below posted code. But, For some reason, eclipse underscores the methods `setIcon` and `setTitle` with red squiggle.
I do not know what I am missing in the code?

Java_Code:

```
reportAlertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.report_dialog);
ImageView reportAlertDialogIcon = 
          (ImageView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogIconID);
reportAlertDialog.setIcon(reportAlertDialogIcon);
TextView reportAlertDialogTitle = 
         (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogTitleID);
reportAlertDialog.setTitle(reportAlertDialogTitle);
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/reportRealtiveLayout00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="top|left">
          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/reportDialogIconID"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/reporticon01"/>
          <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/reportDialogTitleID"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reportDialogIconID"
              android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `inflate layout` and set to your `AlertDialog` like

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)yourActivity.this.
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,null);

reportAlertDialog.setView(layout);
```

and then reference your `Imageview` and `TextView` with that particular layout

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogIconID);
TextView title=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogTitleID);
```

**Update:**

Set Icon image `Drawble` to your `imageview` like

```
  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

Set title text to your title `TextView` like

```
  title.setTitle("Your Title);
```

Comment: so "setcontentView" would not work? I am not questioning you answer but in a tutorial "setContentView" was used and not the inflater! or it is another alternative?

Comment: @Amr it will. this has nothing to do with what the error is.

Comment: @Amr this is alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

You param for `setIcon` is wrong

```
public void setIcon (Drawable icon)
Added in API level 1

public void setIcon (int resId)
Added in API level 1

Set resId to 0 if you don't want an icon.
Parameters
resId   the resourceId of the drawable to use as the icon or 0 if you don't want an icon.
```

You have

```
reportAlertDialog.setIcon(reportAlertDialogIcon); // is a imageview
```

Use

```
reportAlertDialog.setIcon(yourdrawable);
```

Also

```
TextView reportAlertDialogTitle = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogTitleID);
reportAlertDialog.setTitle(reportAlertDialogTitle); // reportAlertDialogTitle is a textview object
```

is wrong

```
 public void setTitle (CharSequence title)
Added in API level 1

Set the title text for this dialog's window.
Parameters
title   The new text to display in the title.
```

Use

```
reportAlertDialog.setTitle("Your Title);
```

Edit:

If you are looking to set image to your custom `ImageView`

```
reportAlertDialogIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.youriamge);
```

And to set text to `TextView`

```
reportAlertDialogTitle.setText("Your Title");
```

Comment: i will check your answer shorthly, thanks in advance